# Xcelsius - Drawing a box around multiple sliders - how?

Tags: xcelsius

The following instructions are straight from the Quick Start tutorial in Xcelsius, but I have YET to find out how to draw a box around the five sliders - there is nothing on-line either that seems to answer such a basic question!

4.11. Draw a box around the five slider components to select them all. 
4.12. On the Format menu, point to Align, and click Center.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can click on the canvas and hold the mouse down while you drag the mouse over the sliders. A better method though is to take advantage of the `Object Browser` window `CNTRL+4` where you can select controls by `CNTRL + MOUSECLICK` on each. It is well worth the small effort required to key in meaningful names for all of the controls/widgets.